# Docker container running MSSQL-Server in Ubuntu 20.04 base image not starting

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to run MSSQL-Server in Ubuntu 20.04 base image. Image gets created with no errors, but container does not start. Please help. Thanks in advance for your comments and helps. This is the files.

rams/ubuntu:base Dockerfile

```
# Use the official Ubuntu 20.04 as base image
FROM ubuntu:20.04

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    wget \
    software-properties-common \
    dirmngr \
    apt-transport-https \
    lsb-release \
    ca-certificates && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Dockerfile

```
# Use the official Ubuntu 20.04 as base image
FROM rams/ubuntu:base

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y gnupg2 && \
    apt-get clean

# Install MSSQL Server and command-line tools
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.asc
RUN add-apt-repository "$(curl -sSL https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/mssql-server-2022.list)"
RUN apt-get update && \
    ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-server && \
    apt-get clean

RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.asc
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get update && \
    ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17 && \
    ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools && \
    echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc && \
#    source ~/.bashrc && \
    apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev && \
    apt-get clean

# Expose the port for SQL Server
EXPOSE 1433
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  sql_server:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: rams/mssql:base
    container_name: rams-mssql
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
      SA_PASSWORD: "YourStrong!Passw0rd"
      MSSQL_PID: "Developer"
```

I checked the code with ChatGPT but not working.

Comment: When you say it's not starting... are you getting any error messages on the container's console?

Comment: Aside... I recommend installing unixodbc-dev from the Ubuntu repos before pulling in references to the Microsoft repos because Microsoft has a habit of periodically breaking the unixodbc and unixodbc-dev packages that they host.

Comment: You're not using `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest`, so why would you expect the deprecated `SA_PASSWORD` variable to do anything? (btw, it's been `MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD` for a while now.) Have you read through [Quickstart: Install SQL Server and create a database on Ubuntu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu) yet? Are you missing any `mssql-conf` steps?

Comment: Be aware that SQL Server on Linux expects to be run by a lesser-privileged `mssql` user (i.e.: not the `root` user). Where are you creating the `mssql` user? Where are you defining an entrypoint to launch `/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr`?

Answer (score 0):

Since I could not find a fix. I used the following files to fix my situation.

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  ms_sql_server:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
      MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD: "YourStrong@Passw0rd"
      MSSQL_PID: "Developer"
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/opt/mssql
    networks:
      mynetwork:
        ipv4_address: 172.18.0.2

networks:
  mynetwork:
    external: true

volumes:
  db_data:
```

dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest

# Install SQL Server command line tools
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y curl gnupg && \
    curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - && \
    curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools unixodbc-dev

# Add tools to PATH
RUN echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you need to switch the container user and specify an `ENTRYPOINT`. You could try something like this Dockerfile...

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.3-labs
FROM ubuntu:20.04 as foundation
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN /bin/bash <<EOF ## Install dependencies
    set -ex
    apt-get update --fix-missing
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends --yes \
        apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl dirmngr gnupg2 \
        lsb-release software-properties-common unixodbc-dev
    apt-get clean
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
EOF

FROM foundation as squirrel
RUN /bin/bash <<EOF ## Install MSSQL
    set -ex
    curl -sSL https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.asc
    curl -sSL https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/mssql-server-2022.list | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-mssql2022.list
    curl -sSL https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list
    apt-get update --fix-missing
    ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-server msodbcsql17 mssql-tools
    echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
    echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~mssql/.bashrc
    apt-get clean
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
EOF
ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr" ]
EXPOSE 1433
USER mssql
```